# How to show two views of one controller in the same page CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

I have a doubt for few days ago. I hope to explain well, and sorry for my english.

Im working with CakePHP, well, i have some controllers with their own views, etc.. What happens is: i have two functions in my controller, and i want that, when i do mouse click on one element (in this case, google chart pie chart) of my view "ONE", i want to execute the other function of the controller (that renders view "TWO") from the view ONE, BUT, in the SAME page.

I know how to treat the click on pie chart, this isnt the problem. The problem IS, how to keep visible the view ONE when i treat the click on it and go to the other view TWO. So i mean, i want to have in the end, the page default with the two views, ONE and TWO, that each has her own function in controller, it isnt a simple view, like a text, table...

I have tried some solutions: requestaction, href of javascript, helpers... but i dont get the solution.

I'd be very grateful if you could help me! Any question ask me, and i hope to have explained well and that you understand my english!

Greetings!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Have you tried the redirect function? http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html#_redirect

Comment: thanks! it isnt exactly what i want, i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do it is by making element with one of your views and then add this element in the other view. You can simply add an element in your view with `$his->element('ElementName');`. See http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html for more information about elements in cakephp.

Put `$this->element('name');` in a div and using ajax you might be calling the function i guess. So in the controller function write something like this:

```
$this->set('set your variables for the elements here');
$view = new View($this, false);
$content = $view->element('my-element');
json_encode($content);
```

and catch this response in success part of your ajax call.

```
success: function (data){
    $("#div_id").html(data);
}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it is the unique solution? I know about the elements but i didnt know if they were good to do this. I think it's a solution, yes, that i can use.. But if i do this, all the logic from the function of view TWO of controller will go on the element no? Another question: doing by this way, i cant use the line "$this->element('ElementName');" in the correct way in javascript (when i treat the mouse click), any idea how to do this? thankss

Comment: @Preetam if you make an Ajax call for the second view, why render it as an element? You can render it directly. But indeed, using an AJAX call to the second function after a mouse clic seems the right way to do it.

Comment: @Chris: if the element render's a larger html and if it's got more conditions and loops then isn't it a better way to render it by element than writing it again in response?

Comment: Thank you very much Preetam!! and thank you too Chris. I think it will be useful for me! I go to the office on Thursday and i will try it then, but more or less i understand what you explain. But i'm not very experienced in ajax; when exactly to put the "success: fun..." part? Either way, i have to try it to say you anything! Thank you very much again! Greetings.

Comment: I mean "where"*, no "when"* ^^

Comment: @Preetam ok, i have tried the solution you gave me, and it seems to be in the correct way, but i dont get the complete solution. I explain; i have put the success part of ajax in the treat of mouse click, ok? The "$this->element('name')" on a div in layout when i want to show the element,and finally the other part (json encode and so) in the function of ¿view ONE? of my controller. But, when i do click, the div shows the actual page, not the element, what happens? If i quit the part of "json encode.." from the function, the result is the same, it looks like this part makes anything, any idea?

Comment: did you try to see what is ajax response in console panel of firebug??

Comment: I just did that, and it shows me two lines, one of them, exactly the SAME url that i'm just now, via GET, and another one that is an .js file that I have for the menu.

Comment: well, in the console of firebug, in "html", i can see that de div "tablediv", where i want to put the view TWO, is filled with ALL the content of the actual page, basically, the entire actual page. It looks like the json_encode dont pass the information to the function ajax, as "data", correctly.

Comment: Ok, i have achieved to show the second function in the div!! I use in the controller function '$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()', and if yes, i create the view through the element, i pass this argument to the second function to stablish the variables and I do "echo" it. But there is a problem, how can i identify what selection i do on the graph?? I mean, if i want to execute this or other function deppending on the selection before send the ajax petition, can i identify it? Thank you very much!!

Comment: sorry for replying late. So about your question, to know about the selection you will have to see through the generated pie chart or if that doesn't work see google's api for the pie chart and try to find how do they define each part of the pie. If each part has got any different id that no problem at all, just take the id and send the data using it. If you want further help please describe about he pie a little more and how you are using it, what data you want to send with it. I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help @Preetam !! No problem! Well, I think that yes, it is simple but i dont get "to hit the nail on the head". Each part of pie chart has different id, so i can treat in javascript dinamically according to the part i do click. But the problem is how exactly know in controller function what "selection[id]" has been clicked on, to call one function or other. Thank you very much!!

Comment: OK!! I have achieved this putting on data part of the ajax call the following: $.ajax({data: "&selec="+selection[0], success...); and I get it on the controller function by $_GET['selec'] !! Thank you very much Preetam, your help has been invaluable!! See you later then.